# How to Call Jquery variable in image tag in html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, image, onchange

I created an ajax script which fetch data and changes on onChange event, I am getting the full image link stored in the database

> I want to call that image link into the img tag in html. I stored that full image link in the variable.
>   I just want to call the variable in img tag. Kindly need help on this
>   any type of guidance would be accepted and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Jquery**

```
var image_link_from_db = './assets/images/my_image.gif' // stored image link..

$('#some_image_id').attr('src',image_link_from_db);  

 OR

$('img').attr('src', image_link_from_db); // this assumes your img tag has no id attribute.
```

add Jquery to your html file and try the above snippets.

Comment: i had id, but i am getting confused in how to call in it with jquery to that <td>, i also tried with ,text() but that .text() is returning as string o.e. "<---between in it----> "

Comment: text() will set or return the text content of an element. But in our case, we want to dynamically change the src attribute of the <img> tag. So to do this, give your <img> tag an 'ID'  attribute sey <img src="some_path" id="some_id" height="" widht="" />. Now to dynamically change the value of the src attribute in jquery. Try this: $('#some_id').attr('src', image_link_from_db'). image_link_from_db is the variable that you've set that you want to now set in <img> src attribute. Hope this helps. I will try and get you further resources, perhaps a link or tutorial to throw more light. Thanks.